# How to open application page on check in button click in document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, custom-form, check-in

For a document library ,while checking in document, I need to open a customized check in form on click of check  in button instead of opening inbuilt form.

Does anybody know how to do this ?

Thanks
Mitesh

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong the Check-in button is a custom action. I suggest to look how publishing feature changes navigation links in site settings page. By default there are two links - one for the Quick Launch Navigation and second for the Top Navigation, but after activation of publishing feature you can see only one link - navigation. After research you can find out that this feature simply uses [HideCustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx) functionality and [adds a new custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643.aspx) functionality to change links. I hope you can use this approach to solve your issue.